# Android ffmpeg0.8 is not compiling with android ndk5 with cygwin compiler

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am using the following tutorial for ffmpeg compilation .

http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/

I am followed all the instructions which they have provided. have changed the path in 
**build_android.sh** ,
i am using android ndk5 and cygwing latest compiler. 
But i am facing following issue. .so file is not gets created .

```
Krajesh@Rajesh /cygdrive/D/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/FFMPEG_2
$ /cygdrive/d/Android_NDK/android-ndk-r5/ndk-build
Prebuilt       : libffmpeg.so <= jni/ffmpeg-0.8/android/armv7-a/
Install        : libffmpeg.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so
install: cannot open `/cygdrive/D/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/FFMPEG_2/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so' for reading: Permission denied
/cygdrive/d/Android_NDK/android-ndk-r5/build/core/build-binary.mk:305: recipe for target `/cygdrive/D/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/FFMPEG_2/libs/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so' failed
make: *** [/cygdrive/D/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/FFMPEG_2/libs/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so] Error 1
```

Can any one please explain why i am getting that permission denied issue and how to overcome that . i am using windows 7 pc.

Thanks.
Rajesh K

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to switch to latest NDK (r8d as of today). You don't need cygwin to work with it, and it is much friendlier altogether. Use ndk-build.cmd instead of the bash script, and quite likely your build will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The fix was to `chmod 777` the problematic .so file in the `/obj/.../` dir.